# Set Xcode Configuration used w/ Fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, fastlane

I have an app with multiple configurations.

These allow me to use `.xconfig` files to ensure my app points at my dev or production environment, depending on the build.

1. Debug
2. Development
3. Testing
4. Release

I am now trying to migrate to Fastlane and would like to create a lane that handles my dev pushes and a lane that handles my app store deploys.

How can I tell a lane which configuration setting to use during build time?

An example, here is the lane that pushes to Crashlytics, it should us the `Testing` config but my default is using `Release`

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push new Crashlytics build"
  lane :dev_push do
      ensure_git_status_clean
      clear_derived_data
      version = get_version_number
      build = increment_build_number

      build_app(
          workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", 
          scheme: "MyApp",
          export_method: "ad-hoc", 
          include_bitcode: false,
          export_options: {
              uploadBitcode: false,
              uploadSymbols: true,
              compileBitcode: false
          }
      )
      changelog_from_git_commits(
          commits_count:1
      )
      crashlytics(
          api_token: "....", 
          build_secret: "....",
          groups: "test"
      )
      commit_version_bump(
        xcodeproj:"MyApp.xcodeproj",
        message: "#{version} (#{build})"
      )
      dev_notification
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`build_app` takes an additional argument that can specify the config used.

```
     build_app(
          workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", 
          scheme: "MyApp",
          configuration: "Debug",
          export_method: "ad-hoc", 
          include_bitcode: false,
          export_options: {
              uploadBitcode: false,
              uploadSymbols: true,
              compileBitcode: false
          }
      )
```

You can find more examples in the [Fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_ios_app/#4-examples)